# Fetching rows based on integer interval of a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using rails 5.0.0 and postgresql

I have 3 tables namely `orders`, `cart_items` and `products`. The relation among them is as follows :
    orders has_many cart_items
    cart_item belongs_to product

Products table contains the price of the product.

What I want to do is fetch the number of orders between the price range of 2500 like orders which contain products worth between 0-2500, 2500-5000 and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll want to look at using [`group`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group)

Comment: But how will I use group for an integer range?

Comment: I am getting results if I use the following:
>p = Product.joins(cart_item: :orders)
>p1 = p.where(orders:{price:0..2500})
>p2 = p.where(orders:{price:2500..5000})`
But I cannot find a way to generalise it.

Answer (score 2):

The concept here is to group each orders by their `total_price` divided by 2500 (we're speaking about integer division here), so you will be able to group by their "sliced category".

Because:

300 / 2500 = 0
400 / 2500 = 0
2500 / 2500 = 1
3000 / 2500 = 1
3000 / 2500 = 1
4999 / 2500 = 1
5000 / 2500 = 2

etc. It's the result of this integer division that will create what I called earlier the "sliced category" (1 => 0-2500, 2 => 2500-5000, 3 => 5000-7500, etc). Since your total price may be decimal or floats, I "round" the value and cast them with `::integer`.

The query can be something like this:

`SELECT count(*), (sliced_2500_category + 1) * 2500 AS sliced_2500_group
FROM (
  SELECT c.order_id, ROUND(SUM(price))::integer / 2500 AS sliced_2500_category
  FROM cart_items c 
  INNER JOIN products p ON c.product_id = p.id
  GROUP BY c.order_id
) orders_by_2500_category
GROUP BY sliced_2500_category;`

Comment: code which also will give correct result provided query is not appended

```maximum_product_price = Product.order("price desc").where("price is not null").limit(1)[0]['price']
lower = 1
upper = 2500
increment = 2500
no_of_ranges = ((maximum_product_price.to_f)/increment).ceil
orders = Order.joins(cart_items: :product)
price_range = []
price_range_count = []
no_of_ranges.times do |count|
orders = orders.select("products.id").where(products:{price:lower..upper})
price_range << "#{lower}-#{upper}"
price_range_count << orders.size
lower += increment 
upper += increment
end
end```

Comment: All the conditions are coupled as a single query like 

```
 Where (price between 1 and 2500) and (price between 2501 and 5000)

```

Comment: @PalakChaudhary The query I was giving is agnostic of any maximum value for a total order price and doesn't do n+1 query. Happy you found your own solution though :-)

Comment: But my query has issues. Even though there is a loop, only one query is being executed with all the conditions combined.
How can I avoid that?

Comment: I had a little issue in my code. Now it worked. Thank you so much

Comment: @PalakChaudhary glad you found your answer. There's a better way of thanking at SO, accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `cart_items` also `belongs_to :orders`
and `product` model `has_many cart_items`
I'm guessing you want to select the invoices/carts which are in the range of 0-2500 and so on..
Raw SQL:

```
SELECT order_id, sum(price)
FROM cart_items c INNER JOIN products p
ON c.product_id = p.id
GROUP_BY order_id
HAVING sum(price) BETWEEN 0 AND 2500
```

Required statement for controller:

```
CartItem.joins(:product)
        .select(:order_id, 'sum(price)')
        .group(:order_id)
        .having('sum(price) BETWEEN 0 AND ?', params[:your_upper_limit_variable])
```

Comment: But the upper limit of the price goes on over 5000. Isn't there a way to generalise it?

Comment: @PalakChaudhary Updated :)

Comment: I think he wants by sliced group (0-2500, 2500-5000, 5000-7500, etc). It's totally possible.

Comment: I want to fetch the number of orders based on price range. So what I want is
0-2500 : Number of orders
2501-5000 : Number of orders and so on.

Comment: @d34n5 : That's exactly what I want

Comment: @PalakChaudhary I will post the query, just have to test. Can you give the details of each relevant columns for each tables? BTW, you won't be able to achieve this with ActiveRecord, since there's lots of aggregation here.

Comment: @d34n5 Great, I'm on it too. Never did this before :)

Comment: maximum_product_price = Product.order("price desc").where("price is not null").limit(1)[0]['price']
    lower = 1
    upper = 2500
    increment = 2500
    no_of_ranges = ((maximum_product_price.to_f)/increment).ceil
    orders = Order.joins(cart_items: :product)
    price_range = []
    price_range_count = []
    no_of_ranges.times do |count|
        orders = orders.select("products.id").where(products:{price:lower..upper})
        price_range << "#{lower}-#{upper}"
        price_range_count << orders.size
        lower += increment 
        upper += increment
    end
  end

Comment: I have used the above logic. But when I call this piece of code, all the conditions are appended to a single query and I am not getting correct result.